# Creating new user using useradd ,but fails since its unable to create group in Oracle Linux 6

Tags: linux, ole, chef

Below is the terminal execution

```
[root@machine chef-server]# useradd -s '/bin/sh' -d '/opt/chef-server/embedded' -r chef_server
useradd: Can't get unique system GID (no more available GIDs)
useradd: can't create group
[root@machine chef-server]# uname -a
Linux machine 2.6.39-300.20.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 12 04:30:55 PST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What is preventing the group creation?

The command  is generated by Chef server reconfigure command and i don't have any control on it.

Comment: is the server stand alone or does it run something like NIS?  what do your /etc/group look like are you out of unique GID?

Answer (score 8):

Just add `SYS_GID_MIN` and `SYS_GID_MAX` inside `/etc/login.defs`:

```
SYS_GID_MIN               2000
SYS_GID_MAX               9000
```